# SQL Server 2012 creating an update looping over 500 existing columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I wish to update date columns with NULL values using an existing value plus 5 years, PK is `IdentityCourseID`.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
UPDATE IdentityCourses
SET Expiry = DATEADD(year, 5, IdentityCourses.DateAttained)
WHERE IdentityCourseID = (SELECT IdentityCourseID
                          FROM IdentityCourses 
                          INNER JOIN UnitIdentities ON  IdentityCourses.IdentityID = UnitIdentities.IdentityID
                          WHERE (IdentityCourses.CourseID = 1041) 
                            AND (UnitIdentities.IsActiveMember = 1) 
                            AND (UnitIdentities.EndDate IS NULL) 
                            AND (IdentityCourses.Expiry IS NULL) )
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the "Update From" Syntax. See this question for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
UPDATE ic
SET Expiry = DATEADD(year, 5, ic.DateAttained)
FROM IdentityCourses AS ic
INNER JOIN UnitIdentities AS ui
  ON ic.IdentityID = ui.IdentityID
WHERE ic.CourseID = 1041
  AND ui.IsActiveMember = 1
  AND ui.EndDate IS NULL
  AND ic.Expiry IS NULL
```